# incrond is firing my rclone but the rclone is not working... but from the command line the rclone command works fine

Tags: inotify, incrond

So in my incrond I have the following:

```
/home/mounts/localdisk/LINUXBACKUP/binlog/ IN_ATTRIB,IN_CREATE,IN_CLOSE_WRITE rclone sync /home/mounts/localdisk/LINUXBACKUP/binlog/ GoogleDLinux:LINUXBACKUP/BINLOGS/
```

in my sys.log I I can see in my syslog that the command fires off both with the incrond watching the folder and if I run

> Oct 26 13:38:48 server incrond[9355]: (root) CMD (rclone copy /home/mounts/localdisk/LINUXBACKUP/binlog/ GoogleDLinux:LINUXBACKUP/BINLOGS)
>
> Oct 26 13:38:48 server incrond[9355]: (root) CMD (rclone copy /home/mounts/localdisk/LINUXBACKUP/binlog/ GoogleDLinux:LINUXBACKUP/BINLOGS)

first one is from the incrond second is from the command line as root.

first one no file gets copied...second one the files gets copied no issues.

I’m not sure why this will run from the command line and not from incrond when the commands being executed in syslog are the same

Comment: You might want to add some more details, and the question itself :-) Of course we know, that you want the solution to the problem being the incron run command does not work, but having a clear question does make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to verbose mode and saw the command was trying to call an non existent rclone config file....fixed that and could now see the issue

I need to put the rclone config under root and not under the normal useer